# Django forms - Post

Tags: python, django, forms, post

One of my form fields is a Foreign Key drop down. When the form is submitted I need to get the selected value in `views.py`.

However, instead of getting (using `request.POST.get('value', False)`) the value I am getting a number (which seems to be arbitrary).

How can I get the selected value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, please show us the relevant parts of your template and your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the ID of the related object.

Since you say you're using a form, you shouldn't be accessing data via `request.POST`, but by `form.cleaned_data`, which will do the work to translate that into the actual object.